# Python: Two objects seem to be referencing the same variable even though I do not have any explicit connection between them

Tags: python, list, object-reference, object-slicing

I am trying to change an octet based on the mask I have. 
Lets say I have IP: 194.216.35.54 and mask- 27, I need to change the 4th octet (3 when counted from 0). I am trying to change the values in the `work_octets` variable. But, somehow, the values in the `network_octets` are also changing. Why is this happening? both `network_octets` and `work_octets` are two different lists created by looping over the values and slicing the `ip_dict_list`. How is it that `network_octets` getting changed- can any one please help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Note: I can deepcopy and change this behavior, but I need to know what is it that I am doing wrong here. Any explanation in this regard is highly appreciated.

Code:

```
octet = 3
ip_dict_list = dc(self.ip_dict_list) # looks like this: [{1: {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 1: 0, 16: 0, 32: 0, 8: 0}}, {2: {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 1: 0, 16: 0, 32: 0, 8: 0}}, {3: {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 1: 0, 16: 0, 32: 0, 8: 0}}, {4: {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 1: 0, 16: 0, 32: 0, 8: 0}}]

vals = [v for i in ip_dict_list for k, v in i.items()]
network_octets = vals[:octet]
work_octets = vals[octet:]
ip_list = ip.split('.')
iof = int(ip_list[octet])  # ip octet in focus (54)
for i in range(len(work_octets)):
    for ob in self.bit_placement:  # loop over the list [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
        # 32 < 54
        if ob <= iof:
            print "Iof: {}, Ob: {}".format(iof, ob)
            iof = iof - ob  # 54-32 = 22; 22-16 = 6; 6-4: 2; 2-2 = 0 (done)
            work_octets[i][ob] = 1  # {32: 1, 16: 0, 8: 0, 4: 0, 2: 0, 1:0 }
            if iof == 0:
                break

Iof: 54, Ob: 32
Iof: 22, Ob: 16
Iof: 6, Ob: 4
Iof: 2, Ob: 2
print work_octets # as expected
[{128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}]
```

> Now network_octets also got changed and I expect it to remain the same - not as expected

```
print network_octets 
[{128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}, {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}, {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}]
```

> This should be unchanged and should look like this:

```
network_octets
[{128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 0, 32: 0}, {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 0, 32: 0}, {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 0, 32: 0}]

The variable vals is also changing after the for loop:
vals
[{128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}, {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}, {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}, {128: 0, 64: 0, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 0, 8: 0, 16: 1, 32: 1}]
```

I expect only the work_octets to have the changes in the values of the dict element and the network_octets and vals should remain same. But all the variables are getting modified after the for loop

Comment: What is that  `dc` call there?

Comment: Can you prepare a working example, please.

Comment: dc is just a deepcopy

Comment: @mikuszefski I have added the inline comments suggesting the values that these variables contain, this code snippet should work with those values and in the description, I have mentioned the IP and mask examples

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but I am just too lazy to figure out what `ip` is, as it is not declared etc. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are so helpful.

Comment: Python never copies anything unless explictely asked for, so your `network_octets` and `work_octets` lists (as a side note: the english term is 'byte' not 'octet') are pointing to the same dicts. You definitly want to read this to understand how python's variables work: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of code, and your snippet is not executable as is,
so it is a bit difficult to give definitive answers.
Nevertheless, I think the problem lies in how you created your lists.

If I understood your code correctly,
`network_octets` and `work_octets` are two lists of dictionaries.
But those are the same dictionaries, so even if you have different lists
(i.e. `network_octets is work_octets` will be `False`),
their contents are the same
(i.e. `network_octets[0] is work_octets[0]` will be `True`).
Therefore, when you assign `work_octets[i][ob]`,
you also touch the dictionary in `network_octets[i]`.
You can confirm that by printing `ip_dict_list`,
which should have changed as well.

We can reproduce the problem with a more minimal example:

```
source = [{0: 10, 1: 20}, {0: 30, 1: 40}, {0: 50, 1: 60}]
l1 = source[:2]
l2 = source[:2]

# Prints 'True'
print(l1[0] is l2[0])

# Here we're effectively touching `l1[0][0]` *and* `l2[0][0]`
l1[0][0] = 100

# Prints '[{0: 100, 1: 20}, {0: 30, 1: 40}]'
print(l2)
```

You don't necessarily need to deep copy everything.
You can focus only on the objects you're modifying.
For instance, in my example it would boil down to the following:

```
# ...
l1[0] = dict(l1[0])
l1[0][0] = 100

# Prints '[{0: 100, 1: 20}, {0: 30, 1: 40}]'
print(l1)

# Prints '[{0: 10, 1: 20}, {0: 30, 1: 40}]'
print(l2)
```

Be careful in your code, as the comments suggest your lists actually contain dictionaries of dictionaries.
Hence, the aforementioned problem would also apply if you only shallow-copy the outer ones.
A deep-copy will surely be safer, but also more expensive if it can be of any concern.

You can try to *print-debug* with `is` (like I did in my examples) or `id` to make sure dictionaries are different before you alter them:

```
# Prints '4406947912 4406947912'
# Obviously the numbers could be different every time you run your code.
print(id(l1[0]), id(l2[0]))
```

Comment: That explains the problem. Thanks @Alvae and @ bruno desthuilliers